# why bash changing my command 'mysql*' to 'mysql.sql'?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, yum

**I am sure that there is no such file called mysql.sql in the directory**

The operating system infor

```
cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
```

I have a shell script. One line is returning nong zero code

```
yum install -y mysql*  1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

When I run this line in terminal, everything is fine and the return code( echo $?) is zero.

But in script, it will return 1 and whith the -x option, I can see bash changing the line into

```
yum install -y mysql.sql
```

So why mysql* is changed to mysql.sql?

Comment: @oguzismail I know wildcard expansion. But the yum should install all packages that start with mysql. So why only change to mysql.sql? Why not some other packages like mysql-connector-python mysql-devel...

Comment: Questions about expansion of `*` are better to be asked on [unix.se].

Answer (score 2):

There is a file called mysql.sql in the current directory of the script.

Quote the argument to avoid bash expanding it, so that yum can.

```
yum install -y "mysql*"  1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

In general, you *always* want to quote arguments with `*` if you don't want them expanded as a glob. Bash by default passes them through literally if they don't match anything, but you can't usually guarantee that, so it's best to just quote it.